# How do I pass input values to a new div in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a CV Generator and I don't know how to properly append the `school` and `field of study` values to a new div inside React.

Using the `onSubmit` function I'm able to get the values after filling them out and clicking save, but I can't figure out where to go from here.

**Update**

What I want to do is take the values from the input and create a new div above the form that displays those values. For example, I want the `School` value to show

*School: University of Whatever*

And the same goes for `Field of Study`.

*Field of Study: Whatever*

I know how to do this in vanilla JS but taking the values and appending them to the DOM but it doesn't seem to work that way in React.

```
class Education extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const schoolForm = document.getElementById("school-form").value;
    const studyForm = document.getElementById("study-form").value;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1 className="title">Education</h1>
        <div id="content">
            <form>
              <label for="school">School</label>
              <input
                id="school-form"
                className="form-row"
                type="text"
                name="school"
              />
              <label for="study">Field of Study</label>
              <input
                id="study-form"
                className="form-row"
                type="text"
                name="study"
              />
              <button onClick={this.onSubmit} className="save">
                Save
              </button>
              <button className="cancel">Cancel</button>
            </form>
          )}
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Education;
```

Comment: can you explain what exactly do you want to do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) in order to save the values then show it when the user submits.

```
import React from "react";
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { scool: "", study: "", showOutput: false };
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      showOutput: true
    });
  };

  setStudy = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      study: value
    });
  };

  setSchool = (value) => {
    this.setState({
      school: value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <h1 className="title">Education</h1>
        <div id="content">
          {this.state.showOutput && (
            <>
              <div>{`school: ${this.state.school}`}</div>
              <div>{`study: ${this.state.study}`}</div>
            </>
          )}
          <form>
            <label for="school">School</label>
            <input
              id="school-form"
              className="form-row"
              type="text"
              name="school"
              onChange={(e) => this.setSchool(e.target.value)}
            />
            <label for="study">Field of Study</label>
            <input
              id="study-form"
              className="form-row"
              type="text"
              name="study"
              onChange={(e) => this.setStudy(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={this.onSubmit} className="save">
              Save
            </button>
            <button className="cancel">Cancel</button>
          </form>
          )
        </div>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I have also added 2 functions to set state and a [condition render](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) based on showOutput.

Comment: You can implement the reset for the cancell button aswell

Comment: thank you, Sky! This worked great. I've been dealing with this problem for 2-3 days now and I just can't seem to fully grasp State. How did you learn?

Comment: @Dagger I am glad that it was helpful. As I have linked in my answer you can learn everything from www.reactjs.org. I highly recommend follow its documentation and tutorial. It will gives u almost anything you need from react library.

Answer (score 1):

You **don't append things to the DOM** in react like you do in vanilla. You want to **conditionally render elements**.

Make a new element to display the data, and render it only if you have the data. (Conditional rendering is done with && operator)

```
{this.state.schoolForm && this.state.studyform && <div>
    <p>School: {this.state.schoolForm}</p>
    <p>Field of Study: {this.state.studyForm}</p>
</div>}
```

The schoolForm and studyForm should be **component state variables**. If you only have them as variables in your onSubmit, the data will be lost after the function call ends. Your onSubmit function should only set the state, and then you access your state variables to use the data.

**Do not use** `document.getElementById`. You don't want to use the 'document' object with react (Almost never).

You can access the element's value directly using the event object which is automatically passed by onSubmit.

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target.school.value)
    console.log(event.target.study.value)
}
```